# How can I use pan gestures to zoom a camera in and out

Tags: 2d, camera, godot

I have the following scene tree for my player:

[image]

They have a `Camera2D` as a child, which has a script attached to it. How can I make the camera zoom in and out as I pan on e.g. a MacBook trackpad?

Answer (score 1):

You can zoom a camera in and out by handling the [`InputEventPanGesture`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.1/classes/class_inputeventpangesture.html) input event:

```
extends Camera2D

var maximum_zoom_in = 0.15
var minimum_zoom_out = 4
var zoom_sensitivity = 0.01

func _unhandled_input(event):
    if event is InputEventPanGesture:
        var zoom_amount = event.delta.y * zoom_sensitivity
        var new_zoom = zoom.y + zoom_amount
        if (new_zoom < maximum_zoom_in):
            new_zoom = maximum_zoom_in
        elif (new_zoom > minimum_zoom_out):
            new_zoom = minimum_zoom_out
        zoom = Vector2(new_zoom, new_zoom)
```